# How can I specify to link the static library in CMake on MacOS, when I have both dynamic and static one?

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, static-linking

As the title described, I want to link one static library in case the environment cannot find the paths in runtime. Also, except this library, other dependencies should be linked through their dynamic libraries.

But it seems that no elegant way to do so in cmake.

Now I have `../\_lib/libsrpc.a` and `../\_lib/libsrpc.dylib`, there are two ways to link libsrpc.a, and keep other libraries dynamic at the same time.

**Method 1** : specify suffix `.a`

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a" ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES})                              
find_library(Srpc_LIB srpc HINTS ../_lib)                                      
                                                                              
target_link_libraries(my_execute_demo ${Srpc_LIB} workflow pthread)
```

**Method 2** : **not available on MacOS**

```
target_link_libraries(my_execute_demo -Wl,-Bstatic srpc -Wl,-Bdynamic workflow pthread)
```

So how can I write the `-Wl,-Bstatic` on MacOS to specify some libraries or there is some other solutions? Thanks.